# Python 3.8 script freezes on getting database connection (psycopg2 and multiprocessing) - Windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, database-connection, psycopg2

I have a script that starts four process to make inserts on a database. They share the same target code with different arguments.

After some debugging, I noticed that the moment that the program got stuck was on the step 2: the step when the process asks for a database connection. The problem does not happen right away. The program accomplishes some inserts before freezing. I tried to lock the steps 2,3 and 4 together, but it didn't solve the problem. I have no idea on how to attack the problem.

records is a array of objects that have data that gonna be used make INSERTs into the database.
counter is a shared value to verify progress.
total is for calculating the progress in percentage.
lock is for exclusive access to variables and database.
dataBaseAdapter is a python module that imports psycopg2 for making connection with database
The database is a PostgreSQL
I don't know if it make any difference, but i am running this on Visual Studio Code

Processes' creation:

```
len_records = len(records)
counter = Value('i', 0)
lock = Lock()
total = Value('i', len_records)

for index in range(0,len_records,4):
    p1 = encapsulatedProcess(index,jogos,len_records,counter,lock)
    p2 = encapsulatedProcess(index+1,jogos,len_records,counter,lock)
    p3 = encapsulatedProcess(index+2,jogos,len_records,counter,lock)
    p4 = encapsulatedProcess(index+3,jogos,len_records,counter,lock)
    holdProcess(index+1,p1)
    holdProcess(index+2,p2)
    holdProcess(index+3,p3)
    holdProcess(index+4,p4)
```

ensapsulatedProcess:

```
def encapsulatedProcess(ind,records,len_records,counter,lock):
    if(ind > len_records): return None
    record = records[ind]
    process = Process(target=my_function, args=(ind,record,counter,lock,), daemon=True)
    process.start()
    return process
```

holdProcess:

```
def holdProcess(number,process):
    if(process == None): return
    if(process.is_alive()):
        process.join()
    process.close()
    print(number)
```

my_function:

```
def dramaAnalizerLocal(idt,record,counter,lock):
    lock.acquire()
    print(idt," 1 - load model")
    auxiliar = Model(record) #connects with database and closes
    lock.release()

    lock.acquire()
    print(idt," 2 - getting connection")
    conn = dataBaseAdapter.getConnection() 
    lock.release()

    lock.acquire()
    print(idt, " 3 - saving data")
    record.store(InsertIntoType1(model=auxiliar, ignored=1), conn)
    record.store(IntertIntoType2(model=auxiliar, ignored=1),conn)
    record.store(InsertIntoType3(model=auxiliar, ignored=1),conn)
    lock.release()

    lock.acquire()
    print(idt," 4 - closing connection")
    dataBaseAdapter.closeConnection(conn)
    lock.release()

    lock.acquire()
    print(idt," 5 - increment counter") 
    counter.value += 1
    lock.release()

    lock.acquire()
    print(idt," 6 - return")
    lock.release()
```

Comment: Does the issue still occur with just one process? I don't see any immediate cause but I think you have far too many locks. The database should be perfectly happy to handle multiple concurrent connections so you really only need the lock to ensure transaction safety in your local objects.

Comment: Also, it could be worth trying in Python 3.7 as I've previously seen issues with psycopg in 3.8 but they could well be fixed now

Comment: About Python 3.7, i tried running it on Anaconda but it did not help. About testing with just one process, I tried that: I restarted the computer and run the program with just 1 process. After 14th execution of my_function, the script got stuck on step 1, when asking for connection. Should I change the problem's description?

Comment: Have you tried checking the postgres logs to see if a connection is actually being made and if there's any error there?

Comment: When the program hangs, no error is printed on log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching on the internet, the problem appeared to be that the program was opening and closing connections too fast. So, it was suggested to close just after all operations. I was able to pass a connection through a single process, but, i don't know how, the process continued to ask for connections. So, to solve the problem, i did the thing i was afraid to do, because i was afraid it would be hard: installing pgbouncer. It turned out to be easy. I just needed to change the port the program used, give a database alias to pgbouncer and restart the pgbouncer.

TLDR: Installed pgbouncer and configured the program and pgbouncer